# Why does mongo throw a memory error while selecting a plan

Tags: mongodb

I'm in the process of upgrading an application to use Mongo 4.4 (from 4.2) and I'm receiving a concerning error message:

```
(line breaks inserted for readability)
'MongoError: multiplanner encountered a failure while selecting best plan
:: caused by
:: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.
Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.\n'
```

I'm aware that the sort limit is being exceeded, this part isn't what concerns me - I was occasionally seeing this portion of the error prior to upgrading to 4.4

The concerning piece here is the new error prefix: `multiplanner encountered a failure while selecting best plan` - the implication here is that mongo *might* have been able to serve the query as is - but while it was selecting the plan, it errorred out.

Does anyone know if mongo throws this error during plan selection, even if there were a plan it could have used that wouldn't have thrown this error? Essentially, is mongo throwing this error more often and potentially incorrectly?